# virtual Host + socket.io Error 404 - Node.js

Tags: nodejs, socket.io, virtualhost

Hola tengo un problema y es que tengo una conexion a mi server.js(no estoy en mi local, en localhost funcion perfecto) estoy utilizando node.js y uso socket.io para los resultados de mis peticiones, el detalle esta que en mi servidor local no puedo usar localhost/ y necesito accesar a mis websockets desde afuera. 
yo he tratado de crear un vhost, para acceder a el pero me da error 404. cuando ejecuto el cliente que hace la peticion.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express(); 
var vhost = require( 'vhost' );  
var connect = require( 'connect' ); 
app.use(vhost('demo.dominiouno.com', express.static( appconnect )));
```

htvhost.conf (he creado este virtual host en mi apache, pero no sirve)

```
<VirtualHost *:3003>
  ServerName demo.dominiouno
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\u2b2b\sockets\server"
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\u2b2b\sockets\server">
 AllowOverride all
</Directory>    
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPass / http://demo.dominiouno:3003/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3003/  
</VirtualHost>
```